# divide ways on a map in parts of length one

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have these coordinates:

```
coord = [(10,10), (13,10), (13,13)]
```

Now i need new coordinates. 
The way between two coordinates is always one.
For example:

```
(10,10)
(11,10)
(12,10)
(13,10)
(13,11)
(13,12)
(13,13)
```

Any ideas?

#

I found the solution.

```
for n in range(len(coord)-1):
    lengthx = coord[n+1][0] - coord[n][0]
    lengthy = coord[n+1][1] - coord[n][1]
    length = (lengthx**2 + lengthy**2)**.5
    for m in range(length):
        print coord[n][0]+lengthx/length*m, coord[n][1]+lengthy/length*m
```

Comment: Looks like Python at first glance, but questioner should definitely add a language tag.

Comment: @kame, can `x` and `y` vary in the same step? E.g. can we assume that `[(10, 10), (12, 12)]` gives `[(10, 10), (11, 11), (12, 12)]`?

Comment: Okay - this is really dumb, but **both** duplicates just got closed!  We should reopen one of them!

Comment: (Voting to reopen since the dupe was also closed, and questioner provided more information here.)

Comment: Sorry for the double posting. Accident!

Comment: @Frederic No the distance has to be one.

Comment: @kame, that's what I thought. `x` first or `y` first? :)

Comment: x first! But I think I found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple variation on [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.literateprograms.org/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm_%28Python%29) will achieve what you want using integer arithmetic only (so it should be noticeably faster):

```
def steps(path):
    if len(path) > 0:
        for i in range(1, len(path)):
            for step in steps_between(path[i - 1], path[i]):
                yield step
        yield path[-1]


def steps_between(start, end):
    x0, y0 = start
    x1, y1 = end

    steep = abs(y1 - y0) > abs(x1 - x0)
    if steep:
        x0, y0 = y0, x0
        x1, y1 = y1, x1

    if y0 > y1:
        x0, x1 = x1, x0
        y0, y1 = y1, y0

    if y0 < y1:
        ystep = 1
    else:
        ystep = -1

    deltax = x1 - x0
    deltay = abs(y1 - y0)
    error = -deltax / 2

    y = y0
    for x in range(x0, x1):
        if steep:
            yield (y, x)
        else:
            yield (x, y)

        error += deltay
        if error > 0:
            y += ystep
            error -= deltax
            if steep:
                yield (y, x)
            else:
                yield (x, y)
```

---

```
coords = [(10, 10), (13, 10), (13, 13)]
print "\n".join(str(step) for step in steps(coords))
```

The above prints:

```
(10, 10)
(11, 10)
(12, 10)
(13, 10)
(13, 11)
(13, 12)
(13, 13)
```

Of course, Bresenham works as expected when both `x` and `y` change between two points on the path:

```
coords = [(10, 10), (13, 12), (15, 13)]
print "\n".join(str(step) for step in steps(coords))
```

That prints:

```
(10, 10)
(11, 10)
(11, 11)
(12, 11)
(12, 12)
(13, 12)
(14, 12)
(14, 13)
(15, 13)
```